# Extjs can't access store by 'setRootVisible' error

Tags: extjs, extjs5

When I used a tree example from Extjs Kitchen Sink 5 to make my own tree. I will get a 'setRootVisible' error like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setRootVisible' of undefined
```

I used this example from kitchen sink: [Sencha Kitchen Sink](http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#basic-trees)

Viewpanel:

```
Ext.define('app.view.dashboard.widget.Tree', {
extend: "Ext.panel.Panel",
xtype: 'tree',

requires: [
    'app.store.Trees',
    'Ext.layout.container.VBox'
],

controller: "dashboard-tree",

viewModel: {
    type: "dashboard-tree"   
},

layout: {
    type: 'hbox',
    pack: 'start',
    align: 'stretch'
},

defaults: {
    xtype: 'treepanel',
    frame: false,
    rootVisible: true, // when true, the 'root' map will be shown 
    store: 'trees' // select store wich contains the tree data
},

initComponent: function() {
    // declare all items of the tree 
    this.items = [{
        flex: 1
    }];
    this.callParent();
}
});
```

This tree store comes from Sencha Kitchen Sink:

```
Ext.define('app.store.Trees', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
xtype: 'store',

root: {
    text: 'Ext JS',
    expanded: true,
    children: [
        {
            text: 'app',
            children: [
                { leaf:true, text: 'Application.js' }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: 'button',
            expanded: true,
            children: [
                { leaf:true, text: 'Button.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Cycle.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Split.js' }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: 'container',
            children: [
                { leaf:true, text: 'ButtonGroup.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Container.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Viewport.js' }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: 'core',
            children: [
                {
                    text: 'dom',
                    children: [
                        { leaf:true, text: 'Element.form.js' },
                        { leaf:true, text: 'Element.static-more.js' }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: 'dd',
            children: [
                { leaf:true, text: 'DD.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'DDProxy.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'DDTarget.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'DragDrop.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'DragDropManager.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'DragSource.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'DragTracker.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'DragZone.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'DragTarget.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'DragZone.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Registry.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'ScrollManager.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'StatusProxy.js' }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: 'core',
            children: [
                { leaf:true, text: 'Element.alignment.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Element.anim.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Element.dd.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Element.fx.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Element.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Element.position.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Element.scroll.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Element.style.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Element.traversal.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Helper.js' },
                { leaf:true, text: 'Query.js' }
            ]
        },
        { leaf:true, text: 'Action.js' },
        { leaf:true, text: 'Component.js' },
        { leaf:true, text: 'Editor.js' },
        { leaf:true, text: 'Img.js' },
        { leaf:true, text: 'Layer.js' },
        { leaf:true, text: 'LoadMask.js' },
        { leaf:true, text: 'ProgressBar.js' },
        { leaf:true, text: 'Shadow.js' },
        { leaf:true, text: 'ShadowPool.js' },
        { leaf:true, text: 'ZIndexManager.js' }
    ]
}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this might not completely solve your issue, I believe that you are extending ExtJs classes incorrectly:

```
Ext.define('app.view.dashboard.widget.Tree', {
    extend: "Ext.panel.Panel",
    xtype: 'tree',
```

Should extend the ExtJs Tree Panel class, not a standard panel, like so:

```
Ext.define('app.view.dashboard.widget.Tree', {
    extend: "Ext.tree.Panel"
```

The xtype config item can be used in the following ways:

You can create a generic Ext.Widget and define its xtype, using example from the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-xtype) here:

```
var text1 = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
     fieldLabel: 'Foo'
 });

 // or alternatively:

 var text1 = Ext.widget({
     xtype: 'textfield',
     fieldLabel: 'Foo'
 });
```

Or you can define your own xtypes like so:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.PressMeButton', {
    extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
    xtype: 'pressmebutton',
    text: 'Press Me'
});
```

Reference: [Sencha Documentation | Ext.Component](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-xtype)

Comment: The set rootVisible error is solved when I have used your solution. But the tree is still don't show any item from the store. Do you now what I can do to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Now it works fine for me. The only thing I must do was to declare the trees store for the items inside the `initComponent: function() {}`.

The solution I have used to get the store is like this:

```
initComponent: function() {
    // declare store
    this.store = new app.store.Trees();

    // declare all items 
    this.items = [{
        title: 'treeTest',
        flex: 1
    }];
    this.callParent();
},
```

I think the store couldn't be recognized by the items. But now it works fine.